# Check engine light turns off after jump start

Tags: voltage

So basically there has been a check engine light on my car for almost 2 weeks now. I took a risk today and went out with freinds to get food. My freind accidentally left the door open which left the light on in the car.  It died and we had a freind come to jump start it. I noticed an hour later that the check engine light is no longer on. I now know that my car had low voltage but did jump starting the car give it a temporary fix or did I just mess up my whole car?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what the check engine light was for or what kind of car, I can only surmise what that issue is, but, but your car needing a jump start, the battery was depleted to need this. This caused the ECU (Engine Control Unit) to be blanked, erasing the codes which caused the check engine light in the first place, and thus turning the check engine light off.

I'd give it a high probability this is only a temporary situation. More than likely, once the system catches up with itself, the problem will rear its head again and the CEL will come back on.